# Java: Transaction processing system

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I have the tables `accounts` and `action`. `accounts` needs to be modified according to the instruction stored in `action`.
In `action` each row contains an account-id, an action (i=insert, u=update, d=delete, x=invalid operation) and an amount by which to update the account.

- On an insert, if the account already exists, an update should be done
  instead
- On an update, if the account does not exist, it is created by an
  insert
- On a delete, if the row does not exist, no action is taken

---

**Input**

accounts:

```
+---id----value--+
|   1  |   1000  |
|   2  |   2000  |
|   3  |   1500  |
|   4  |   6500  |
|   5  |    500  |
+----------------+
```

action:

```
+---account_id---o---new_value---status---+
|       3      | u |     599   |          |
|       6      | i |    2099   |          |
|       5      | d |           |          |
|       7      | u |    1599   |          |
|       1      | i |     399   |          |
|       9      | d |           |          |
|      10      | x |           |          |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

---

**Output**

accounts:

```
+---id----value--+
|   1  |    399  |
|   2  |    800  |
|   3  |    599  |
|   4  |   1400  |
|   6  |  20099  |
|   7  |   1599  |
+----------------+
```

action:

```
+---account_id---o---new_value-------------------status----------------+ 
|       3      | u |     599   | Update: Success                       |
|       6      | i |   20099   | Update: Success                       |
|       5      | d |           | Delete: Success                       |
|       7      | u |    1599   | Update: ID not founds. Value inserted |
|       1      | i |     399   | Insert: Acc exists. Updated instead   |
|       9      | d |           | Delete: ID not found                  |
|      10      | x |           | Invalid operation: No action taken    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

I am experienced with Java and JDBC, but unfortunately I just don't know, how to start here.
Do I need an additional table? Do I have to use triggers?

Comment: What have you done for that ?

Comment: Do you have to put this entirely into SQL?  Or can the status messages generated from java code?  If it's in java code, then, your logic above should be pretty easy to code.  Regardless, you're going to put the resolving of i,o,u into java code, so you can do the rest of the logic there also, without the need for triggers and the like.

Comment: No, it's up to me, how to solve it. I just don't know how to start. Do I need additional tables?

Comment: @user1170330, your problem statement essentially describes reading each row from the action table, doing what it says, and updating its status.  Very little creativity is being asked for.

Comment: So I just need to pass through each row in `action`, modify `account` accordingly and then update the colum `status` in `action`? And I don't need additional tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen two techniques for an upsert.  With the first technique, within a transaction, you test first to see if the row exists, and use the results to determine whether to perform an insert or an update.  With the second technique, you try performing an update and verify the number of records updated (JDBC gives you this).  If it's zero, then you do an insert, if one, then you're done.

Comment: The second approach will be faster because with the first approach the check for existence will be done twice (update, insert will need to check that anyway).